# Regular expression for matching string

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a regex that will match any string like this one:  `AA-12-DF-AA` .

The matching string will have these parts:

1. two capital letters (it would be the same char twice)
2. two digits
3. two capital letters, but different from the first part
4. another two capital letters, matching with the first part

All parts are separated with '-'

e.g this is valid strings:

```
BB-43-DF-BB 
CC-99-DD-CC 
XX-21-AB-XX
```

Comment: From these two `XX-21-XX-XX`, `XX-21-AX-XX` which one you want to match?

Comment: the second one `XX-21-AX-XX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
^(([A-Z])\2)-\d{2}-(?:(?!\1)[A-Z]){2}-\1$
```

Comment: this matches AA-24-AA-AA too, but it shouldn't

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Sure, that's what I get after first attempt that somebody downvoted. It's natural that we propose same answer, but don't worry I've already given you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(([A-Z])\2)-\d{2}-(?:(?!\1)[A-Z]){2}-\1$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sM4zG2/3)

Comment: you wrong: in your case `AB-32-CK-AB` will match too, and it's required first 2 chars to be the same

Comment: yes, see the third rule. `two capital letters, but different from the first part`

Comment: ? I mean it should not match, but it does, I've tried with your demo

Comment: Why it should not be matched?

Comment: Read the question carefully: `two capital letters (it would be the same char twice)`

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili thanks updated.. Could you revert back the vote, because now it's correct..

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:([A-Z])\1)-\d{2}-(?!\1)[A-Z]{2}-\1\1$
```

Try this.This fulfills all the conditions.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/32

Comment: why this `XX-21-BX-XX` not matched?

Comment: So `BX` is different from `XX`

Comment: Yes, let's ask him, he means I'm true

Comment: I did not do it ;) but if someone did, he can't cancel it after some minutes passed from the action, so if you corrected the answer, it sometime may be late

Comment: see the op's comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232884/regular-expression-for-matching-string#comment41145818_26232884